Is there a way that a calendar can be shared with full permissions to create/edit/change with just a shareable link?
Trying to create a shared calendar for my music community.
Ideally I want to be able to send people a link and they can access with full permissions but currently the closest I can get is to make it public and share a link but even then they don't have permission to edit anything, only view.
Is the only options to get their emails and add their permissions manually?
